# Finding the height of a triangle in terms of its (non-obtuse) base angles and base length

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

> If we have triangle $\varDelta ABC$, how to find the value of the height ($BD$) of a given triangle, if we have the values ​​of the $\angle BAC$ and $\angle ACB$ expressed in degrees, if we assume that the length $AC $ is equal to 1, and if we also assume that the value of given angles is not higher than $90$ degrees?

For example, if the value of the $\angle ACB$ is 45 degrees and the value of the $\angle BAC$ is $45$ degrees, the height of a given triangle is obviously $0.5$, or if the values ​​of the angles are $60$ degrees and $30$ degrees, the height of the triangle is $0.4330127 $... , if the value of the $\angle ACB$ in degrees is ${x}$ and the value of the $\angle BAC$ in degrees is ${y}$ (${x}$ < $90$, and ${y}$ < $90$)), my solution is

$$\frac{1}{{\cot}\left(\frac{{\pi}}{360}\cdot2{x}\right)+{\cot}\left(\frac{{\pi}}{360}\cdot2{y}\right)}$$
($1$ in the formula represents the value of $AC$, just as an example, of course the value of $AC$ can be any value)
Also my solution for the $AD$ length
$$\frac{1}{\frac{{\cot}\left(\frac{{\pi}}{360}\cdot2{x}\right)}{{\cot}\left(\frac{{\pi}}{360}\cdot2{y}\right)}+1}$$
whether my formulas give correct results and what is some other way to solve this problem

to concretize the question if $x=35$ and $y=80$ the value of $BD$ is

$$\frac{1}{{\cot}\left(\frac{{\pi}}{360}\cdot 2 \cdot {35}\right)+{\cot}\left(\frac{{\pi}}{360}\cdot2\cdot{80}\right)}=0.62325.. $$
and AD is

$$\frac{1}{\frac{{\cot}\left(\frac{{\pi}}{360}\cdot2\cdot{35}\right)}{{\cot}\left(\frac{{\pi}}{360}\cdot2\cdot{80}\right)}+1}=0.10989...  $$

whether these values ​​are correct?

Answer (score 1):

> If we have triangle ΔABC, how to find the value of the height (BD) of a given triangle, if we have the values ​​of the ∠BAC and ∠ACB expressed in degrees, if we assume that the length AC is equal to 1, and if we also assume that the value of given angles is not higher than 90 degrees?

You are given two angles, which implies that you can calculate the 3rd angle.  Further, since one of the sides of the triangle is known, you can use the [Law of Sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines), to calculate the lengths of the other two sides.

Then, using [Heron's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula), you can calculate the area of the triangle.

Note that the calculated area (**also**) equals $~(1/2) \times ~$ base $~\times~$ height.  Since the area is now known, and since the pertinent base is known, you can calculate the pertinent height.

---

**Edit**
Well, this is embarrassing.  I thought of a shortcut which allows you to avoid having to focus on the area of the triangle.

Once the pertinent side of a triangle and pertinent angle of a triangle are known, you can calculate the pertinent height directly.

That is height $~=~ \sin(\theta) \times ~$ pertinent side.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "pertinent", but yes,$$BD = (BA)\sin \angle BAC\\BD = (BC)\sin \angle BCA$$